# Create an in-page anchor with CKeditor 5

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

Implementing CKEditor 5 into one of our projects. I would like to allow the end-user to create an in-page anchor tag that they can jump to using other links (i.e `<a name='internalheading'>` that can be jumped to via `<a href="#internalheading">`). I'm not sure if it's possible, but can I use CKeditor's built-in link functionality to create the anchor link as well as the link to it? If so how?

Comment: did you find any solution to this.

Comment: Nope. Never did find any answer to this.

Comment: This is enormously frustrating. Even when I can create this. CKEditor5 always navigates to a new page... More help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

Many, many people want the ability to create in-page links with anchor name or ID, so this is reported to be coming to CKEditor 5… soon, but no promised date: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues/1944

There is a CKEditor 5 package to provide this anchor feature about contemporaneous to this question:

https://github.com/bvedad/ckeditor5-anchor

It has proven itself useful enough that there is an adaptation of it to make it easy to install on Drupal sites using CKEditor5:

https://github.com/northernco/ckeditor5-anchor-drupal

This may help you if you are getting the following message in your update of CKEditor 4 to 5 in Drupal: "The CKEditor 4 button Anchor does not have a known upgrade path. If it allowed editing markup, then you can do so now through the Source Editing functionality."